# Applying a "Sum(Filter(" to a range using ArrayFormula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I'm having an issue making a formula becoming an array. The formula I have as of now is

Cell S3 =

```
=sum(FILTER('Junkyard 2'!$G$3:$H,'Junkyard 2'!$B$3:$B>=$S$5,'Junkyard 2'!$B$3:$B<=$T$5,
'Junkyard 2'!$C$3:$C=N8
```

(Junkyard 2 is where all the data gets dumped. S5 and T5 are dates. So basically I'm trying to get a list of numbers that is between 2 dates and that matches the name of the guy (Cell N8) and the adding the total hours. This was a workaround as I could not get the sumifs to work)

I've made it in a way that even if user were to insert another row, the formula would apply to the new row as well by doing this

Cell S3 =

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(R7:R)=7,"", sum(FILTER(
'Junkyard 2'!$G$3:$H,'Junkyard 2'!$B$3:$B>=$S$5,'Junkyard 2'!$B$3:$B<=$T$5,
'Junkyard 2'!$C$3:$C=N8
```

My issue right now is I can't apply this to the whole S3:S.
By changing the last part to

```
'Junkyard 2'!$C$3:$C=N8:N would not give me the proper answer.
```

Can anyone help me apply this to a range?
The image below is the "Junkyard 2 Sheet"
[image: Reference]

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do might be most easily achieved with the `QUERY` formula ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?hl=en)) as you can filter and aggregate in one command with much more flexibility than `SUMIFS`.

Try adjusting this formula to your needs:

```
=QUERY('Junkyard 2'!B3:H, 
       "SELECT SUM(G) + SUM(H) 
        WHERE B >= date '" & TEXT(U4, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND 
              B <= date '" & TEXT(U5, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND 
              C = '" & U6 & "'")
```

Comment: Im not sure but when I tried it it does not apply it to the whole column but only one cell.
But even then, I get this 

    sum(sum sum)
    90

If i apply my formula 
(=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B7:B="","",ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(S7:S)=7,"",QUERY('Junkyard 2'!B3:H, 
       "SELECT SUM(G) + SUM(H) 
        WHERE B >= date '" & TEXT(S5, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND 
              B <= date '" & TEXT(T5, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND 
              C = '" & B7:B & "'"))))))
it populates all the rows with "sum(sum sum)"

Comment: Try appending ` LABEL SUM(G)+SUM(H) ''` to the end of the query. That will remove the headers and should just display the result.

Comment: I am very new to query thing, I've tried adding it at the end and got an formula parse error. Please help me

Comment: Did you add it to the end of the second argument to Query?

Comment: yeah like this? 
'=QUERY('Junkyard 2'!B3:H, 
       "SELECT SUM(G) + SUM(H) 
        WHERE B >= date '" & TEXT(S5, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND 
              B <= date '" & TEXT(T5, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND 
              C = '" & B8 & "'" `"LABEL SUM(G)+SUM(H) ''`")'

pretty sure somethign is wrong

Comment: if you could write it out for me that would be great. I'll mark it as done then

Comment: Can you share the spreadsheet (or a sample)? That would make it easier to get a working version working

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MNfB0IbY7FL5ZgjGrD9NFlgBZLrmy5CsXE1BjNLzL9Q/edit#gid=477508537
you can see it here

Comment: This formula is applied in Fronters Tab, on the right side, under "late"